# Laravel Homestead - No input file specified?

Tags: laravel, debian, vagrant, virtual-machine, homestead

I am trying to install a Homestead VM for Laravel development on Debian Linux 8 with Vagrant 1.8.4 and VirtualBox 5.0.24 r108355.

Following the [official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/homestead), I have installed Homestead and configured it in `Homestead.yaml` in the following way:

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: ~/Code/dev.todoparrot.com
      to: /home/vagrant/Code

sites:
    - map: dev.todoparrot.com
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/dev.todoparrot.com/public

databases:
    - homestead

# blackfire:
#     - id: foo
#       token: bar
#       client-id: foo
#       client-token: bar

# ports:
#     - send: 50000
#       to: 5000
#     - send: 7777
#       to: 777
#       protocol: udp
```

To test it with a sample file, I have created an `index.php` in `/home/user/Code/dev.todoparrot.com/public/` on my local machine that echos a string:

```
<?php echo "Hello from Homestead!"; ?>
```

I have also added `dev.todoparrot.com` to `/etc/hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       debian
192.168.10.10   dev.todoparrot.com

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Within the `Homestead` folder of my local machine, the VM starts both via `vagrant up` and `vagrant up --provision`, but when I visit the domain http://dev.todoparrot.com/ in the browser, I get the following error:

**No input file specified.**

Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: Navigate to /home/vagrant/Code and install laravel there

Comment: Try change to:
folders:
    - map: ~/Code

and then vagrant up --provision

Comment: That solved it: Browser displays "Hello from Homestead!". Quiet strange..

Comment: It's because you don't have dev.todoparrot.com folder on your vagrant machine. It was like  "/home/vagrant/Code/public". If you go to  vagrant ssh and check "Code" folder you will understand that that folder "dev.todoparrot.com" doesn't exist)

Comment: @dkruchok Ok, thanks a lot for your explication.

Comment: In that case @dkruchok write an answer and user3046831 must accept it to help other poeple finding the solution :)

Answer (score 0):

> No input file specified

It says that you don't have any file in

> /home/vagrant/Code/dev.todoparrot.com/public

For now, your Vagrant path is

> /home/vagrant/Code/dev.todoparrot.com/

And you looking for **dev.todoparrot.com/public** in **dev.todoparrot.com**

That's your issue

You need change

```
folders:
- map: ~/Code/dev.todoparrot.com
  to: /home/vagrant/Code
```

to:

```
folders:
- map: ~/Code
  to: /home/vagrant/Code
```

It will emulate all folders in **Code** to **/home/vagrant/Code/**

Run `vagrant up --provision` after every update of *Homestead.yaml*

And in the future, you need to change/add only

```
sites:
- map: project-name.app
  to: /home/vagrant/Code/ProjectName/public
```

Use `vagrant ssh` to check your current folders structure inside **Code**

Answer (score 0):

If you already tried

> vagrant up --provision

and still you getting 'No input file specified' error, try to run

> vagrant reload --provision

reload vagrant box works for me.